# How to use Secure RPC?

Tags: security, winapi, ipc, rpc

I'm using RPC ( Remote Procedure calls) for local process communication. I have used ncalrpc protocol, wrote a typical server using APIs RpcServerUseProtseqEp, RpcServerRegisterIf, RPCServerListen and a typical client using RpcStringBindingCompose,RpcBindingFromStringBinding. All looks good till now, client and server communicate using a remote method.

Now I am evaluating the option to make this communication secure. I need to take care of 3 aspects mainly, Client authentication, Authorization and data private & integrity.
RpcBindingSetAuthInfo allows me to set the authentication level and authorization service and a SPN. RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY can be used for authentication and encrypts data.
1. But I didn't understand who really does the authentication and how ?

1. I didn't understand how the SecurityCallback that can be registered on server side using RpcServerRegister helps me to check authorized clients.
2. I didn't get who does the authorization and how ? I am not sure in which cases does authorization required and how it is achieved in RPC. My application communicates on local machine only.

Someone please clarify my queries.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

if your app runs locally, it's ok with no encryption RPC call.
In case you want to test RPC call with encryption, make sure

1. call RpcServerRegisterAuthInfo(0, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, 0, 0) on server
   side.
2. call RpcBindingSetAuthInfo(hRPCBind, 0, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, 0, 0) on client side,

windows will handle the rest, such as encryption, transport.